# Can i call the function in insert satement using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, function, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to insert data into a table. But i need the department value from database table.So i create a function in database and call this through the below code. I got the syntex error.

```
MySqlCommand InsertQueryToMysqlDB = new MySqlCommand("insert into employee(Employee_ID,Employee_Name,Department,Punchdate,Day,Intime) values('" + Empid + "','" + EmpName + "','fn_getdept('" + Empid + "')','" + PDate + "','" + Day + "','" + Time + "')", con);
```

Comment: you should be using paremeterized query or make stored procedure

Comment: @user3085540 you need to Execute your query like `InsertQueryToMysqlDB.ExecuteNonQuery();` and also used paramerter

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are can be some other mistakes too. You've put quotes everywhere. They should only surrond the non-numeric(`string`, `datetime`, `guid`, etc.) values.

**Update:** But if your function returns a non-numeric value you shouldn't surround it(the function call) with quotes since it will already be in quotes when returning from the function.

Example:

if your `Empid` is `int` it should be called like this:

```
"....values(" + Empid + ",...."
```

if your function returns `string` and gets `int` as parameter:

```
"....values(...., fn_getdept(" + Empid + "),...."
```

I hope you get the essence of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you parameterize your queries, they'll be easier to maintain and you'll be less likely to run into issues with missing / extra / mismatched apostrophes.

```
var insertCommand = new MySqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO employee(Employee_ID, Employee_Name, Department, Punchdate, Day, Intime) " +
    "VALUES(@Empid, @EmpName, fn_getdept(@Empid), @PDate, @Day, @Time)", con);

insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empid", Empid);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpName);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDate", PDate);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", Day);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Time);
```

Comment: Never mind the fact that he's exposing himself to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Grant Winney add **@** like `@"INSERT INTO employee(Employee_ID...` to escape **+**

Comment: if you have **@** it doesn't matter you have more than a newline just like `@"SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT
             invoicetable.invid as `id`,
             invoicetable.`refno` as `refno`,
             cmtable.date as `TIMESTAMP`
             FROM
             cmitemtable
             INNER JOIN invoicetable ON invoicetable.invid = cmtable.invid
             ) AS t 
             WHERE
             DATE(t.`TIMESTAMP`) =@DateTime";

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make it simple... any query you can do in the SQLMMS, you can run from your C# ExecuteNonQuery.